# Snowflake - Need to show previous 7 days' data per tenant

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, calculated-columns

I have a (possibly silly) question. I have to create a view in Snowflake where I have a date column, tenant, count(number_of_requests) and count(number_f_collections). This part I've done and am happy with.

Basic code below:

```
select date_trunc(day, CREATED)::date as CREATED_DATE,
    TENANT,
    count(distinct case when comment = 'Non personalised order created' then SIMNO end) as NUMBER_OF_REQUESTS,
    count(distinct case when comment = 'Non personalised order collected by customer' then SIMNO end) as NUMBER_OF_COLLECTIONS
from <DATABASE>.<SCHEMA>.<TABLE>;
```

The second part is what I'm struggling with. In the same view they want a column that contains the count of requests per tenant in the last 1-7 days, requests sent 1-12 days, and then 1-25 days. The same will be for collections. I have no clue how to even do this. Please see required column names.

- CREATED_DATE
- TENANT
- NUMBER_OF_REQUESTS
- NUMBER_OF_COLLECTIONS
- NUMBER_OF_REQUESTS_1_7_DAYS_AGO
- NUMBER_OF_REQUESTS_1_12_DAYS_AGO
- NUMBER_OF_REQUESTS_1_25_DAYS_AGO
- NUMBER_OF_COLLECTIONS_1_7_DAYS_AGO
- NUMBER_OF_COLLECTIONS_1_12_DAYS_AGO
- NUMBER_OF_COLLECTIONS_1_25_DAYS_AGO

Any help would be very highly appreciated.

I essentially only managed to create the base code. I tried using between dates, interval - 7, etc. None of it works.

> The results will be something like:
>
> | Date | Tenant | No_Requests | No_Collections | Request_1_7Days | Request_1_12Days | Request_1_25Days | Collection_1_7Days | Collection_1_12Days | Collection_1_25Days |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 12/1/2023 | Tenant1 | 65 | 46 | 455 | 780 | 1625 | 322 | 552 | 1150 |
> | 12/2/2023 | Tenant2 | 56 | 53 | 392 | 672 | 1400 | 371 | 636 | 1325 |
> | 12/3/2023 | Tenant3 | 124 | 94 | 868 | 1488 | 3100 | 658 | 1128 | 2350 |
> | 12/4/2023 | Tenant4 | 176 | 82 | 1232 | 2112 | 4400 | 574 | 984 | 2050 |

Comment: Is the calculation for "7 days ago" based on the current date or the created date? It would probably be helpful if you updated your question with sample data and the result you want to achieve - as editable text formatted as tables

Comment: Hi there. I'm sorry for sounding stupid, but how can I do this?

Comment: By editing your question and typing in the information. https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables

Comment: Thank you! I updated my question. Hope it helps.

Comment: Jus to clarify, the 7 days is based on the created_date for each row? So the data in the row for "12/1/2023" is based on data between '11/25/2023" and "12/1/2023" - or is it between '11/24/2023" and "11/30/2023", or something else?

Comment: I'm losing my marbles. It's for CREATED_DATE. For 11/25/2023 it will be from the 24th back.

Answer (score 0):

So if we start with some fake data, and you SQL:

```
with data(created, tenant, comment, simno) as (
    select *
    from values
     ('2023-12-01'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 1),
     ('2023-12-01'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 1),
     ('2023-12-01'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 2),
     ('2023-12-01'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 3),
     ('2023-12-01'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 3)
)
select 
    CREATED::date as CREATED_DATE,
    TENANT,
    count(distinct case when comment = 'R' then SIMNO end) as NUMBER_OF_REQUESTS,
    count(distinct case when comment = 'C' then SIMNO end) as NUMBER_OF_COLLECTIONS
from data
group by 1,2;
```

[image]

we a see you could use simpler date cast, to truncate to day, you "this code works" needs a group by added.

But otherwise is a good start. I am going to assume the key point you are not sure is how to do (and didn't mention) is that the sum on "simno" has a distinct in it, thus there can be duplicate values, and again an assumption, in the 1-7, 1-12, and 1-25 periods you also want distinct counts, thus the aggregation has to happen three times, or we need to use [BITMAPS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-bitmaps-for-distinct-counts).

Given I have never used BITMAPS lets go that way (it the optimal path for huge data, thus the more fun path).

```
with data(created, tenant, comment, simno) as (
    select *
    from values
     ('2023-12-01'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 1),
     ('2023-12-01'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 1),
     ('2023-12-01'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 2),
     ('2023-12-01'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 3),
     ('2023-12-01'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 3),

     ('2023-12-02'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 3),
     ('2023-12-02'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 4),
     ('2023-12-02'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 5),
     ('2023-12-02'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 7),
     ('2023-12-02'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 1)
     
), enriched_data as (
    select *
        ,created::date as created_date
        ,comment = 'R' as is_request
        ,comment = 'C' as is_collection
    from data 
), simno_seq_map as (
    select 
        simno
        ,seq8() as seq
    from (
        select distinct simno
        from data
    )
), mapped_data as (
    select d.*
        ,seq
    from enriched_data as d
    join simno_seq_map as m
        on d.simno = m.simno
), daily_bitmaps as (
    select
        created_date,
        tenant,
        BITMAP_BUCKET_NUMBER(seq) as bit_bucket,
        BITMAP_CONSTRUCT_AGG(iff(is_request, BITMAP_BIT_POSITION(seq), null)) as req_bit_bmp,
        BITMAP_CONSTRUCT_AGG(iff(is_collection, BITMAP_BIT_POSITION(seq), null)) as coll_bit_bmp
    from mapped_data
    group by 1,2,3
)
select 
    created_date,
    tenant,
    sum(r_cnt) as num_requests,
    sum(c_cnt) as num_collections
from (
    select 
        created_date,
        tenant,
        BITMAP_COUNT(BITMAP_OR_AGG(req_bit_bmp)) as r_cnt,
        BITMAP_COUNT(BITMAP_OR_AGG(coll_bit_bmp)) as c_cnt
    from daily_bitmaps
    group by 1,2, bit_bucket
)
group by 1,2
order by 1,2;
```

[image]

Ok, so that lots of work to get to the same place, but now we have daily bitmaps, we can do the combinations of this rows, and have much lower, rows results.

### Adding day 1-7:

```
with data(created, tenant, comment, simno) as (
    select *
    from values
     ('2023-12-01'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 1),
     ('2023-12-01'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 1),
     ('2023-12-01'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 2),
     ('2023-12-01'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 3),
     ('2023-12-01'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 3),

     ('2023-12-02'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 3),
     ('2023-12-02'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 4),
     ('2023-12-02'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 5),
     ('2023-12-02'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 7),
     ('2023-12-02'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 1)
     
), enriched_data as (
    select *
        ,created::date as created_date
        ,comment = 'R' as is_request
        ,comment = 'C' as is_collection
    from data 
), simno_seq_map as (
    select 
        simno
        ,seq8() as seq
    from (
        select distinct simno
        from data
    )
), mapped_data as (
    select d.*
        ,seq
    from enriched_data as d
    join simno_seq_map as m
        on d.simno = m.simno
), daily_bitmaps as (
    select
        created_date,
        tenant,
        BITMAP_BUCKET_NUMBER(seq) as bit_bucket,
        BITMAP_CONSTRUCT_AGG(iff(is_request, BITMAP_BIT_POSITION(seq), null)) as req_bit_bmp,
        BITMAP_CONSTRUCT_AGG(iff(is_collection, BITMAP_BIT_POSITION(seq), null)) as coll_bit_bmp
    from mapped_data
    group by 1,2,3
), data_today as (
    select 
        created_date,
        tenant,
        sum(r_cnt) as num_requests,
        sum(c_cnt) as num_collections
    from (
        select 
            created_date,
            tenant,
            BITMAP_COUNT(BITMAP_OR_AGG(req_bit_bmp)) as r_cnt,
            BITMAP_COUNT(BITMAP_OR_AGG(coll_bit_bmp)) as c_cnt
        from daily_bitmaps
        group by 1,2, bit_bucket
    )
    group by 1,2
), data_1_7_win as (
    select db.*
        ,dateadd('day', w.v, db.created_date) as window_date
    from daily_bitmaps as db
    cross join (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7)) as w(v)
), data_1_7 as (
    select 
        created_date,
        tenant,
        sum(r_1_7_cnt) as num_requests_1_7,
        sum(c_1_7_cnt) as num_collections_1_7
    from (
        select 
            d.created_date,
            d.tenant,
            d.bit_bucket,
            BITMAP_COUNT(BITMAP_OR_AGG(dw.req_bit_bmp)) as r_1_7_cnt,
            BITMAP_COUNT(BITMAP_OR_AGG(dw.coll_bit_bmp)) as c_1_7_cnt
        from daily_bitmaps as d
        join data_1_7_win as dw
            on d.tenant = dw.tenant
                and d.bit_bucket = dw.bit_bucket
                and d.created_date = dw.window_date
        group by 1,2, d.bit_bucket
    )
    group by 1,2
)
select 
    dt.*,
    d7.num_requests_1_7,
    d7.num_collections_1_7
from data_today as dt
left join data_1_7 as d7
    on dt.created_date = d7.created_date
        and dt.tenant = d7.tenant
order by 1,2
;
```

[image]

Alrighty, that was a large lift, firstly we use bucketing of the last 1-7 days, to make more rows, but allows for equi-joins, so that complex but fast. Then we sum the prior days, and bind those with the results, thus to get 1-12, and 1-25, you would most likely want to repeat the `data_1_7_win` CTE but with 12 & 25 values, and then do `data_1_7` for those window values.

Yes this could all be done much the same with range joins, but if you have large amounts of data, that way will perform much slower than this way.

### Full SQL:

```
with data(created, tenant, comment, simno) as (
    select *
    from values
     ('2023-12-01'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 10),
     ('2023-12-01'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 20),
     ('2023-12-01'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 21),
     
     ('2023-11-30'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 30),
     ('2023-11-30'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 31),
     ('2023-11-30'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 32),
     ('2023-11-30'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 40),
     ('2023-11-30'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 41),
     ('2023-11-30'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 42),
     ('2023-11-30'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 43),

     ('2023-11-23'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 50),
     ('2023-11-23'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 51),
     ('2023-11-23'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 52),
     ('2023-11-23'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 53),
     ('2023-11-23'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 54),
     ('2023-11-23'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 60),
     ('2023-11-23'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 61),
     ('2023-11-23'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 62),
     ('2023-11-23'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 63),
     ('2023-11-23'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 64),
     ('2023-11-23'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 65),

     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 70),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 71),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 72),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 73),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 74),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 75),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't1', 'R', 76),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 80),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 81),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 82),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 83),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 84),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 85),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 86),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't1', 'C', 87)   
), enriched_data as (
    select *
        ,created::date as created_date
        ,comment = 'R' as is_request
        ,comment = 'C' as is_collection
    from data 
), simno_seq_map as (
    select 
        simno
        ,seq8() as seq
    from (
        select distinct simno
        from data
    )
), mapped_data as (
    select d.*
        ,seq
    from enriched_data as d
    join simno_seq_map as m
        on d.simno = m.simno
), daily_bitmaps as (
    select
        created_date,
        tenant,
        BITMAP_BUCKET_NUMBER(seq) as bit_bucket,
        BITMAP_CONSTRUCT_AGG(iff(is_request, BITMAP_BIT_POSITION(seq), null)) as req_bit_bmp,
        BITMAP_CONSTRUCT_AGG(iff(is_collection, BITMAP_BIT_POSITION(seq), null)) as coll_bit_bmp
    from mapped_data
    group by 1,2,3
), data_today as (
    select 
        created_date,
        tenant,
        sum(r_cnt) as num_requests,
        sum(c_cnt) as num_collections
    from (
        select 
            created_date,
            tenant,
            BITMAP_COUNT(BITMAP_OR_AGG(req_bit_bmp)) as r_cnt,
            BITMAP_COUNT(BITMAP_OR_AGG(coll_bit_bmp)) as c_cnt
        from daily_bitmaps
        group by 1,2, bit_bucket
    )
    group by 1,2
), data_1_7_win as (
    select db.*
        ,dateadd('day', w.v, db.created_date) as window_date
    from daily_bitmaps as db
    cross join (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7)) as w(v)
), data_1_7 as (
    select 
        created_date,
        tenant,
        sum(r_1_7_cnt) as num_requests_1_7,
        sum(c_1_7_cnt) as num_collections_1_7
    from (
        select 
            d.created_date,
            d.tenant,
            d.bit_bucket,
            BITMAP_COUNT(BITMAP_OR_AGG(dw.req_bit_bmp)) as r_1_7_cnt,
            BITMAP_COUNT(BITMAP_OR_AGG(dw.coll_bit_bmp)) as c_1_7_cnt
        from daily_bitmaps as d
        join data_1_7_win as dw
            on d.tenant = dw.tenant
                and d.bit_bucket = dw.bit_bucket
                and d.created_date = dw.window_date
        group by 1,2, d.bit_bucket
    )
    group by 1,2
), data_1_12_win as (
    select db.*
        ,dateadd('day', w.v, db.created_date) as window_date
    from daily_bitmaps as db
    cross join (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) as w(v)
), data_1_12 as (
    select 
        created_date,
        tenant,
        sum(r_1_12_cnt) as num_requests_1_12,
        sum(c_1_12_cnt) as num_collections_1_12
    from (
        select 
            d.created_date,
            d.tenant,
            d.bit_bucket,
            BITMAP_COUNT(BITMAP_OR_AGG(dw.req_bit_bmp)) as r_1_12_cnt,
            BITMAP_COUNT(BITMAP_OR_AGG(dw.coll_bit_bmp)) as c_1_12_cnt
        from daily_bitmaps as d
        join data_1_12_win as dw
            on d.tenant = dw.tenant
                and d.bit_bucket = dw.bit_bucket
                and d.created_date = dw.window_date
        group by 1,2, d.bit_bucket
    )
    group by 1,2
), data_1_25_win as (
    select db.*
        ,dateadd('day', w.v, db.created_date) as window_date
    from daily_bitmaps as db
    cross join (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),
        (14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23),(24),(25)) as w(v)
), data_1_25 as (
    select 
        created_date,
        tenant,
        sum(r_1_25_cnt) as num_requests_1_25,
        sum(c_1_25_cnt) as num_collections_1_25
    from (
        select 
            d.created_date,
            d.tenant,
            d.bit_bucket,
            BITMAP_COUNT(BITMAP_OR_AGG(dw.req_bit_bmp)) as r_1_25_cnt,
            BITMAP_COUNT(BITMAP_OR_AGG(dw.coll_bit_bmp)) as c_1_25_cnt
        from daily_bitmaps as d
        join data_1_25_win as dw
            on d.tenant = dw.tenant
                and d.bit_bucket = dw.bit_bucket
                and d.created_date = dw.window_date
        group by 1,2, d.bit_bucket
    )
    group by 1,2
)
select 
    dt.*,
    d7.num_requests_1_7,
    d7.num_collections_1_7,
    d12.num_requests_1_12,
    d12.num_collections_1_12,
    d25.num_requests_1_25,
    d25.num_collections_1_25
from data_today as dt
left join data_1_7 as d7
    on dt.created_date = d7.created_date
        and dt.tenant = d7.tenant
left join data_1_12 as d12
    on dt.created_date = d12.created_date
        and dt.tenant = d12.tenant
left join data_1_25 as d25
    on dt.created_date = d25.created_date
        and dt.tenant = d25.tenant
order by 1,2
;
```

gives:

[image]

given I spaced the values out, and they are all distinct id's this makes sense to me.

Add some non-distinct id's:

```
     -- not distinct ids

     ('2023-12-01'::timestamp, 't2', 'R', 10),
     ('2023-12-01'::timestamp, 't2', 'C', 20),
     ('2023-12-01'::timestamp, 't2', 'C', 21),
          
     ('2023-11-30'::timestamp, 't2', 'R', 10),
     ('2023-11-30'::timestamp, 't2', 'R', 11),
     ('2023-11-30'::timestamp, 't2', 'R', 12),
     ('2023-11-30'::timestamp, 't2', 'C', 20),
     ('2023-11-30'::timestamp, 't2', 'C', 21),
     ('2023-11-30'::timestamp, 't2', 'C', 22),
     ('2023-11-30'::timestamp, 't2', 'C', 23),
     
     ('2023-11-23'::timestamp, 't2', 'R', 10),
     ('2023-11-23'::timestamp, 't2', 'R', 11),
     ('2023-11-23'::timestamp, 't2', 'R', 12),
     ('2023-11-23'::timestamp, 't2', 'R', 13),
     ('2023-11-23'::timestamp, 't2', 'R', 14),
     ('2023-11-23'::timestamp, 't2', 'C', 20),
     ('2023-11-23'::timestamp, 't2', 'C', 21),
     ('2023-11-23'::timestamp, 't2', 'C', 22),
     ('2023-11-23'::timestamp, 't2', 'C', 23),
     ('2023-11-23'::timestamp, 't2', 'C', 24),
     ('2023-11-23'::timestamp, 't2', 'C', 25),

     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't2', 'R', 10),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't2', 'R', 11),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't2', 'R', 12),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't2', 'R', 13),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't2', 'R', 14),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't2', 'R', 15),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't2', 'R', 16),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't2', 'C', 20),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't2', 'C', 21),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't2', 'C', 22),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't2', 'C', 23),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't2', 'C', 24),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't2', 'C', 25),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't2', 'C', 26),
     ('2023-11-16'::timestamp, 't2', 'C', 27)
```

we get:

[image]

which is exactly how I imagined, it would look.

### No Nulls:

I assume this is about the left joins I used to connect the prior days, while I agree there is no-null in your data, this code relies of this, aka lets remove the LEFT:

```
from data_today as dt
join data_1_7 as d7
    on dt.created_date = d7.created_date
        and dt.tenant = d7.tenant
join data_1_12 as d12
    on dt.created_date = d12.created_date
        and dt.tenant = d12.tenant
join data_1_25 as d25
    on dt.created_date = d25.created_date
        and dt.tenant = d25.tenant
```

and now get are missing the 2023-11-16 row... because there was no history for this row:

[image]

So from here we can drop the window bucket style and we can drop the bitmap usage..

### No BITMAPS:

```
with data(created, tenant, comment, simno) as (
/* same as above */      
), enriched_data as (
    select *
        ,created::date as created_date
        ,comment = 'R' as is_request
        ,comment = 'C' as is_collection
    from data 
), data_today as (
    select
        created_date,
        tenant,
        count(distinct iff(is_request, simno, null)) as cnt_r,
        count(distinct iff(is_collection, simno, null)) as cnt_c
    from enriched_data
    group by 1,2
), data_1_7_win as (
    select db.*
        ,dateadd('day', w.v, db.created_date) as window_date
    from enriched_data as db
    cross join (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7)) as w(v)
), data_1_7 as (
    select 
        d.created_date,
        d.tenant,
        count(distinct iff(dw.is_request, dw.simno, null)) as cnt_r,
        count(distinct iff(dw.is_collection, dw.simno, null)) as cnt_c
    from enriched_data as d
    join data_1_7_win as dw
        on d.tenant = dw.tenant
            and d.created_date = dw.window_date
    group by 1,2
), data_1_12_win as (
    select db.*
        ,dateadd('day', w.v, db.created_date) as window_date
    from enriched_data as db
    cross join (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) as w(v)
), data_1_12 as (
    select 
        d.created_date,
        d.tenant,
        count(distinct iff(dw.is_request, dw.simno, null)) as cnt_r,
        count(distinct iff(dw.is_collection, dw.simno, null)) as cnt_c
    from enriched_data as d
    join data_1_12_win as dw
        on d.tenant = dw.tenant
            and d.created_date = dw.window_date
    group by 1,2
), data_1_25_win as (
    select db.*
        ,dateadd('day', w.v, db.created_date) as window_date
    from enriched_data as db
    cross join (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),
        (14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23),(24),(25)) as w(v)
), data_1_25 as (
    select 
        d.created_date,
        d.tenant,
        count(distinct iff(dw.is_request, dw.simno, null)) as cnt_r,
        count(distinct iff(dw.is_collection, dw.simno, null)) as cnt_c
    from enriched_data as d
    join data_1_25_win as dw
        on d.tenant = dw.tenant
            and d.created_date = dw.window_date
    group by 1,2
)
select 
    dt.*,
    d7.cnt_r as r_1_7,
    d7.cnt_c as c_1_7,
    d12.cnt_r as r_1_12,
    d12.cnt_c as c_1_12,
    d25.cnt_r as r_1_25,
    d25.cnt_c as c_1_25
from data_today as dt
left join data_1_7 as d7
    on dt.created_date = d7.created_date
        and dt.tenant = d7.tenant
left join data_1_12 as d12
    on dt.created_date = d12.created_date
        and dt.tenant = d12.tenant
left join data_1_25 as d25
    on dt.created_date = d25.created_date
        and dt.tenant = d25.tenant
order by 2,1;
```

gives:

[image]

but takes for this tiny data 1.5s instead on 0.8s

### No BITMAPS No WINDOWS:

So here is the answer you were expecting I believe:

```
with data(created, tenant, comment, simno) as (
/* also trimmed */     
), enriched_data as (
    select *
        ,created::date as created_date
        ,comment = 'R' as is_request
        ,comment = 'C' as is_collection
    from data 
), data_today as (
    select
        created_date,
        tenant,
        count(distinct iff(is_request, simno, null)) as cnt_r,
        count(distinct iff(is_collection, simno, null)) as cnt_c
    from enriched_data
    group by 1,2
), data_1_7 as (
    select 
        d.created_date,
        d.tenant,
        count(distinct iff(dw.is_request, dw.simno, null)) as cnt_r,
        count(distinct iff(dw.is_collection, dw.simno, null)) as cnt_c
    from enriched_data as d
    join enriched_data as dw
        on d.tenant = dw.tenant
            and d.created_date between dateadd('days', 1, dw.created_date) and  dateadd('days', 7, dw.created_date)
    group by 1,2
), data_1_12 as (
    select 
        d.created_date,
        d.tenant,
        count(distinct iff(dw.is_request, dw.simno, null)) as cnt_r,
        count(distinct iff(dw.is_collection, dw.simno, null)) as cnt_c
    from enriched_data as d
    join enriched_data as dw
        on d.tenant = dw.tenant
            and d.created_date between dateadd('days', 1, dw.created_date) and  dateadd('days', 12, dw.created_date)
    group by 1,2
), data_1_25 as (
    select 
        d.created_date,
        d.tenant,
        count(distinct iff(dw.is_request, dw.simno, null)) as cnt_r,
        count(distinct iff(dw.is_collection, dw.simno, null)) as cnt_c
    from enriched_data as d
    join enriched_data as dw
        on d.tenant = dw.tenant
            and d.created_date between dateadd('days', 1, dw.created_date) and  dateadd('days', 25, dw.created_date)
    group by 1,2
)
select 
    dt.*,
    d7.cnt_r as r_1_7,
    d7.cnt_c as c_1_7,
    d12.cnt_r as r_1_12,
    d12.cnt_c as c_1_12,
    d25.cnt_r as r_1_25,
    d25.cnt_c as c_1_25
from data_today as dt
left join data_1_7 as d7
    on dt.created_date = d7.created_date
        and dt.tenant = d7.tenant
left join data_1_12 as d12
    on dt.created_date = d12.created_date
        and dt.tenant = d12.tenant
left join data_1_25 as d25
    on dt.created_date = d25.created_date
        and dt.tenant = d25.tenant
order by 2,1
;
```

which gives the same results as prior:

[image]

On this tiny dataset it performs in the same 1.5s time range on my otherwise idle XTRASMALL warehouse. But when you have the number of rows, I suspect you have they should perform quite differently.

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't give me  what I really need. There won't be nulls in any of the 1- day columns. And 1-12 should be more than 1-7, etc. But thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @DebbieDippenaar I am not sure what you mean by "does not do what you need" can you bridge the gap, so we can help you? and it makes sense the 12 day and 25 day windows would have larger values, so I am not sure what your comment is pointing at.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should give you what you want. You may need to adjust the DATEDIFF calculations to get the precise date window that you want.

```
WITH DAILY_COUNTS AS (
    SELECT TENANT, CREATED_DATE
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN COMMENT = 'Non personalised order created' then 1 ELSE 0 END) NOR
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN COMMENT = 'Non personalised order collected by customer' then 1 ELSE 0 END) NOC
    FROM TENANT_DATA
    GROUP BY TENANT, CREATED_DATE
)
SELECT 
DC1.TENANT, DC1.CREATED_DATE, DC1.NOR, DC1.NOC
,SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,DC2.CREATED_DATE, DC1.CREATED_DATE) < 7 THEN DC2.NOR ELSE 0 END) NOR_1_7
,SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,DC2.CREATED_DATE, DC1.CREATED_DATE) < 12 THEN DC2.NOR ELSE 0 END) NOR_1_12
,SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,DC2.CREATED_DATE, DC1.CREATED_DATE) < 25 THEN DC2.NOR ELSE 0 END) NOR_1_25
,SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,DC2.CREATED_DATE, DC1.CREATED_DATE) < 7 THEN DC2.NOC ELSE 0 END) NOC_1_7
,SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,DC2.CREATED_DATE, DC1.CREATED_DATE) < 12 THEN DC2.NOC ELSE 0 END) NOC_1_12
,SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,DC2.CREATED_DATE, DC1.CREATED_DATE) < 25 THEN DC2.NOC ELSE 0 END) NOC_1_25
FROM DAILY_COUNTS DC1
LEFT OUTER JOIN DAILY_COUNTS DC2 ON DC1.TENANT = DC2.TENANT AND DC1.CREATED_DATE > DC2.CREATED_DATE
GROUP BY DC1.TENANT, DC1.CREATED_DATE, DC1.NOR, DC1.NOC
ORDER BY DC1.TENANT, DC1.CREATED_DATE DESC
;
```

Answer (score 0):

So to test the scale of your data, lets make some data the gives the results you are looking for:

```
create or replace table question_data as 
with params(timestamp, tenant, comment, d0, d7, d12, d25) as (
    select * from values
        ('2023-12-01'::date, 'Tenant1', 'Non personalised order created', 65, 455, 780, 1625),
        ('2023-12-02'::date, 'Tenant2', 'Non personalised order created', 56, 392, 672,1400),
        ('2023-12-03'::date, 'Tenant3', 'Non personalised order created', 124, 868,1488,3100),
        ('2023-12-04'::date, 'Tenant4', 'Non personalised order created', 176, 1232,2112, 4400),
                
        ('2023-12-01'::date, 'Tenant1', 'Non personalised order collected by customer', 46, 322,552,1150),
        ('2023-12-02'::date, 'Tenant2', 'Non personalised order collected by customer', 53, 371,636,1325),
        ('2023-12-03'::date, 'Tenant3', 'Non personalised order collected by customer', 94, 658,1128,2350),
        ('2023-12-04'::date, 'Tenant4', 'Non personalised order collected by customer', 82, 574,984,2050),

        ('2023-12-01'::date, 'Tenant1', 'these match nothing', 65, 455, 780, 1625),
        ('2023-12-02'::date, 'Tenant2', 'these match nothing', 56, 392, 672,1400),
        ('2023-12-03'::date, 'Tenant3', 'these match nothing', 124, 868,1488,3100),
        ('2023-12-04'::date, 'Tenant4', 'these match nothing', 176, 1232,2112, 4400)

), to_dates(timestamp, tenant, comment, simno_cnt) as (
    select
        dateadd('days', -w.d, dateadd('seconds', abs(random())%(24*60*60), p.timestamp)) as timestamp
        ,p.tenant
        ,p.comment
        ,case w.d
            when 0 then p.d0
            when 7 then p.d7
            when 12 then p.d12
            when 25 then p.d25
        end as simno_cnt
    from params as p
    cross join (values (0),(7),(12),(25)) as w(d)
), gens as (
    select 
        row_number() over (order by null) as rn
        ,seq8() as simno
    from table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 4500))
)
select
    p.timestamp
    ,p.tenant
    ,p.comment
    ,g.simno
from to_dates as p
join gens as g
    on g.rn <= p.simno_cnt;
```

which is a table with ~50K rows.

so using the simplest SQL form:

```
with enriched_data as (
    select *
        ,timestamp::date as created_date
        ,comment = 'Non personalised order created' as is_request
        ,comment = 'Non personalised order collected by customer' as is_collection
    from question_data 
), data_today as (
    select
        created_date,
        tenant,
        count(distinct iff(is_request, simno, null)) as cnt_r,
        count(distinct iff(is_collection, simno, null)) as cnt_c
    from enriched_data
    where created_date >= '2023-12-01'::date
    group by 1,2
), data_1_7 as (
    select 
        d.created_date,
        d.tenant,
        count(distinct iff(dw.is_request, dw.simno, null)) as cnt_r,
        count(distinct iff(dw.is_collection, dw.simno, null)) as cnt_c
    from data_today as d
    join enriched_data as dw
        on d.tenant = dw.tenant
            and d.created_date between dateadd('days', 1, dw.created_date) and  dateadd('days', 7, dw.created_date)
    group by 1,2
), data_1_12 as (
    select 
        d.created_date,
        d.tenant,
        count(distinct iff(dw.is_request, dw.simno, null)) as cnt_r,
        count(distinct iff(dw.is_collection, dw.simno, null)) as cnt_c
    from data_today as d
    join enriched_data as dw
        on d.tenant = dw.tenant
            and d.created_date between dateadd('days', 1, dw.created_date) and  dateadd('days', 12, dw.created_date)
    group by 1,2
), data_1_25 as (
    select 
        d.created_date,
        d.tenant,
        count(distinct iff(dw.is_request, dw.simno, null)) as cnt_r,
        count(distinct iff(dw.is_collection, dw.simno, null)) as cnt_c
    from data_today as d
    join enriched_data as dw
        on d.tenant = dw.tenant
            and d.created_date between dateadd('days', 1, dw.created_date) and  dateadd('days', 25, dw.created_date)
    group by 1,2
)
select 
    dt.*,
    d7.cnt_r as r_1_7,
    d12.cnt_r as r_1_12,
    d25.cnt_r as r_1_25,
    d7.cnt_c as c_1_7,
    d12.cnt_c as c_1_12,
    d25.cnt_c as c_1_25
from data_today as dt
left join data_1_7 as d7
    on dt.created_date = d7.created_date
        and dt.tenant = d7.tenant
left join data_1_12 as d12
    on dt.created_date = d12.created_date
        and dt.tenant = d12.tenant
left join data_1_25 as d25
    on dt.created_date = d25.created_date
        and dt.tenant = d25.tenant
order by 2,1
;
```

we get the results you are hoping to get:

[image]

I have a filter in the `data_today` step to only include this months results, so we only see the 4 December results. But renaming columns and putting this in a view should not be too hard from here.

### WORST WAY SQL:

So this SQL is the easiest way to think about this problem, but should be avoid at all costs, I killed this query after 17 hours of running, and with 54B rows having been created by the join-mess, just avoid.

```
select 
    dt.timestamp::date as created_date,
    dt.tenant,
    count(distinct iff(dt.comment = 'Non personalised order created', dt.simno, null)) as cnt_r,
    count(distinct iff(dt.comment = 'Non personalised order collected by customer', dt.simno, null)) as cnt_c,
    count(distinct iff(d7.comment = 'Non personalised order created', d7.simno, null)) as cnt_r_1_7,
    count(distinct iff(d12.comment = 'Non personalised order created', d12.simno, null)) as cnt_r_1_12,
    count(distinct iff(d25.comment = 'Non personalised order created', d25.simno, null)) as cnt_r_1_25,
    count(distinct iff(d7.comment = 'Non personalised order collected by customer', d7.simno, null)) as cnt_c_1_7,
    count(distinct iff(d12.comment = 'Non personalised order collected by customer', d12.simno, null)) as cnt_c_1_12,
    count(distinct iff(d25.comment = 'Non personalised order collected by customer', d25.simno, null)) as cnt_c_1_25
from question_data as dt
left join question_data as d7
    on dt.tenant = d7.tenant
        and dt.timestamp::date between dateadd('days', 1, d7.timestamp::date) and  dateadd('days', 7, d7.timestamp::date)
left join question_data as d12
    on dt.tenant = d12.tenant
        and dt.timestamp::date between dateadd('days', 1, d12.timestamp::date) and  dateadd('days', 12, d12.timestamp::date)
left join question_data as d25
    on dt.tenant = d25.tenant
        and dt.timestamp::date between dateadd('days', 1, d25.timestamp::date) and  dateadd('days', 25, d25.timestamp::date)
where dt.timestamp >= '2023-12-01'::date
group by 1,2
order by 2,1;
```

### So how does this easier to read code stack up, against the BITMAP/Bucket SQL and the WORST WAY SQL

So if we duplicate that question data by 100, 1000, 10000

```
--- 100x
create table question_data_100x as 
select q.* from question_data as q
cross join table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 100));

--- 1,000x
create table question_data_1000x as 
select q.* from question_data as q
cross join table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 1000));

--- 10,000x
create table question_data_10000x as 
select q.* from question_data as q
cross join table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 10000));
```

and then run the two chunks of code:

| Table X | Table Rows | Table Size | Slow SQL (s) | Fast SQL (s) | Worst SQL (s) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50K | 303KB | 0.982 | 0.848 | 17+ hours |
| 100 | 5M | 8.7MB | 6.1 | 2.7 |  |
| 1,000 | 50.3M | 62MB | 13 | 3.2 |  |
| 10,000 | 502.7M | 431.5MB | 67 | 14 |  |

and 66% of the fast sql's time is the `daily_bitmaps` over 500M rows.

With a different set data where more known date ranges (which is not available from a View) both (ignoring the worst) solutions should perform better with tighter filtering.