# SQL Count Distinct with Window Frame or Order

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a sales table that contains the date of sale, and userID. For each date in my table, I'm looking to take the sum of sales, count of unique users, for the previous 365 days from the given date. **Here's my expected output**:

| Sales Date | Trailing 365 day Sales | Trailing 365 day Unique User Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-02-05 | $150,000 | 50,0000 |
| 2024-02-06 | $152,000 | 51,500 |

Here's the code I've attempted:

```sql
SELECT
    sale_date
  , SUM(sales) as total_sales
  , SUM(sales) OVER (ORDER BY sales_date ROWS BETWEEN 365 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) as trailing_365_sales
  , COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) OVER (ORDER BY sales_date ROWS BETWEEN 365 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) as unique_user_count
FROM sales_table
GROUP BY 1
```

The trailing sales line works, but the obvious problem is I can't do a distinct count like this, so I'm looking for any workaround ideas to get the desired output.

Comment: I have no clue what snowflake-cloud-data-platform is but why cant you use a correlated sub query and join based on the sales date, in addition...`<your code>...INNER JOIN (SELECT sales_date, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM someTable GROUP BY sales_date) x ON x.sales_date = yourMainTable.sales_date`

Comment: I believe that would give me duplicate user counts, no? Say I bought yesterday and today, I only want to be counted once.

Comment: Can you provide a few rows of formatted data and desired output? The table DDL an insert statements would be helpful. Or even just a CTE which mimics table data.

Comment: Yeah the CTE would just be: 

SELECT sales_date, userID, sales_amount FROM <table>

Comment: @JonH correlated sub-queries normally are not supported in Snowflake, as the "optimal" rewrite is not clear, where-as the SQL author can normally trivially write valid join based SQL

Comment: if your data is large enough, using COUNT_BITMAP would be the correct way to build the per data distinct data: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/bitmap_count, and then aggregate per user. Here is a example https://stackoverflow.com/a/77643011/43992

Comment: @datacleanupnewb - it would not give you duplicate user counts because it is grouped by date.  So I don't know what your intention is, is it not by date?  It would give you a count for today and a count for tomorrow, which I assume you do not want based on your comment ?

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim I haven't heard of bitmaps before, so I'll take a look at that, thank you

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim Unfortunately my userID is hashed, so it could be a value like "1hy/" which gives me an error with bitmaps

Comment: generate a "id" -> int mapping via a SEQUENT and use that in the bitmap (you want todo this anyways to avoid the sparse values) and then count those.